# how to add spaces in textbox using commandbutton

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a program that can insert spaces in a Textbox
using the command button but it doesn't work at all. Is there any code that can do that?

My code is only setting up a value for the Text box and it only work once what I really want is to insert space every time I click the button.

Here is my simple code:

```
enter code here
Dim space As String = Space(1)
Text1.Text = space
```

Comment: You could just do `TextBox1.Text &= " "`

Comment: Where do you wan to insert the space? Is your textbox contain only space but not any other characters/words? If yes, **TextBox1.Text &= " "** will do, else, please specify your question.

Comment: thanks for the help guys all suggestion works. and now i want to put space anywhere. i mean if i type other characters i can put space before, between or after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Button was clicked, add a space to the textbox...
    Textbox1.Text = Textbox1.Text & " "

    ' OR...
    '  Textbox1.AppendText(" ")
    ' OR...
    '  Textbox1.AppendText(Space(1))
End Sub
```

Etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
Text1.Text = Text1.Text & " "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private sub cmd_sps_click()
Text1.Text = Text1.Text & " "
text1.startposition = text1.length+1
end sub
```